# Unknown moving light in sky

Tags: amateur-observing

On July 13, 2018, while camping in Southwest Oregon, a bright light appeared in the sky at sunset. It was much brighter than Jupiter, also visible. It was moving slowly, west to east. I estimate it took 1/2 hour to cross the sky, though I didn't watch it all the way. The brightness seemed to vary, as did the coloration. It seemed it was reflecting the sunlight. It was higher than the clouds.
   I had a spotting scope with me and it was not a point nor a disc, but rather circular, bright around the edge with a less-bright center. It kind of looked like a planetary nebula, only quite bright. I thought maybe it was a weather balloon, but I really have no idea.

Comment: Sounds like a weather balloon or possibly a "Google Loon" -- a balloon to bring internet service to remote countries. What is the magnification of your spotting scope?

Comment: Good details: date, location, time, direction, speed, description of magnified view; much better than a garden variety UFO sighting.

Comment: Venus is also in the sky at sunset right now and is brighter than Jupiter (which is currently high up in the sky at sunset). Are you sure it's not that?

Comment: Spotting scope is 20 power. There was a hill to the west, obscuring Venus, and the object wasn't traveling in the ecliptic. It crossed very close to the zenith. Hard to get in the spotting scope.